# File Operation does not replace whole line

Tags: c#, .net, io

I'm trying to replace a file line with another one.

here's my block of code

```
string text = readWholeFile(fileName);

text = text.Replace(oldLine, newLine);

IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName,
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, myStore))
{
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine(text);
        isoFileWriter.Close();            
    }

    isoFileStream.Close();
```

the problem is that the Line is only replaced the exact number of newLine characters.For example if OldLine was `1234567890` and newLine is `asd`. The file operation gives output something like this

```
asd
4567890
```

here `readWholeFile` method reads the whole file. and `oldLine` ,`newLine` is the method string parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure you are showing us the whole picture.  [Clearly your replace method replaces the whole string](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RPOUez).  The carriage return in your data is interesting tho.  I dont think your example data matches your output example.  That carriage return in the output is suspect.

Comment: can you show the readWholeFile method? on a side note , you do not need to close the filestream or streamwriter when you have it in a using statement

Comment: I tested a simpler code with the Replace and it worked as expected.

Comment: @paqogomez, the carriage return in the output is there because he is writting using WriteLine, and the output file exists and is not empty. I suspect that during the first attempts he was wrtting the original string to it, and later changed to the replaced, but then the file wasnt empty anymore

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works as expected:

```
string text = "1234567890\n1234567891\n1234567892";
var rText = text.Replace("1234567890", "asd");

Console.WriteLine(rText);
Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is:

```
asd
1234567891
1234567892
```

So, it's obvious that you're problem isn't with the String.Replace method. 
You can use a simple code to "read the whole file":

```
string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in text) 
    str.AppendNewLine(s);
```

And than,

```
var rText = str.ToString().Replace(oldLine, newLine);
```

And finally, save everything to file again:

```
File.WriteAllText(outputFile, rText);
```

**EDIT**

Also, the following code works:

```
string text = "1234567890\n1234567891\n1234567892";

var rText = text.ToString().Replace("1234567890", "asd");

using (var isoFileStream = new FileStream("output.txt",
       FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.Write(rText);                    
    }
}
```

The output, as expected, was:

```
asd
1234567891
1234567892
```

But I found that the following caused problems:

```
using (var isoFileStream = new FileStream("output.txt",
       FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.Write(rText);
    }
}
```

The situation that this caused problems was when the file already exists with the following content:

```
1234567890
1234567891
1234567892
```

The output in the file was:

```
asd
1234567891
1234567892
67892
```

If instead of File.OpenOrCreate the file mode is changed to File.Create, the problem disappears.

**EDIT**

I didn't used "IsolatedStorageFile" just because I'm not testing on a SilverLight context nor using ClickOnce to deploy, and so it won't work

Comment: Just as a side note: Silverlight is not the only place where IsolatedStorage is available, it is also available to desktop and Windows Store applications.